# Will I get banned if I regularly play from different IPs?

Tags: diablo-iii

Am I going to be banned if I play Diablo III from different places (same country but different IP address)? I am based on different locations which changed every 2 weeks or so.

Comment: I'd say not, but knowing Blizzard I wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: Provided you don't do something suspicious (like login from two parts of the country within a matter of minutes) I think you'd be fine.

Comment: Voting to close: We can't predict what blizzard will or will not do. This is also essentially a "legal advice" question, since it really just comes down to what is in the TOS. We're not lawyers, and therefore we're not qualified to answer such questions.

Comment: @Wipqozn "We're not lawyers" is a very weak argument. You might not be a lawyer but others might.

Comment: Even if they were, giving legal advice triggers a whole bunch of uncomfortable stuff related to how attorney-client relationships work and ethical rules handed down from their  respective bar association. Sure, they can disclaim it, but at that point they're giving legal-advice-that-isn't-legal-advice, and then, well.. better to close it and never have the issue come up.

Comment: @nappy We're gaming.SE, not lawyers.SE. We're gaming experts, not law experts, and therefore we don't allow legal questions. [See this meta.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161/should-we-avoid-all-legal-questions)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the terms of service or any other Blizzard policy which prevents it, so nothing bad is supposed to happen, and if it does I'm sure you could convince Blizzard to fix it.

Keep in mind that if you're using an authenticator you might have to enter your code more often than if you would have used a single IP.

Answer (score 1):

No you will not. Diablo 3, like Starcraft 2 are bound to your account. Thus you can install the client as many times you want on different computers or laptops. You can even login with your account when you play on a friends computer. Just logout his account and login with your own.

Blizzard only allows only one computer to be online with your account at the same time.

Most ISP change your IP every 24 hours anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Its "Global Play" enabled for a reason, so i don't think you may be experiencing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I played with my account from Shanghai and Beijing then Hamburg... If that is not triggering some sort of accountprotection, changing the city won't either!

Answer (score 0):

No, most of the users have dynamic ip addresses (at least in Europe), it would be unreasonable to ban them all.